# How to Index-Match against numeric values and display Yes/No results

Tags: excel, indexing, match

I need to match a column in one sheet against info on another sheet.

I've already done this: =INDEX(Sheet3!$G:$G, MATCH([@[Product Name]],Sheet3!$B:$B,0))

Which allows me to bring the actual numeric value over.

I need another version of this formulas that is almost identical, everything is matching on Product name, but should display "Yes / No' based on if the matched field is NULL or has *any* number in it. (Yes if any number) -- The values are in Sheet3!H:H

Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Wrap the Match into an IsNumber(). Then use that as the condition in IF and return Yes or No accordingly

```
=if(isnumber( MATCH([@[Product Name]],Sheet3!$B:$B,0)),"yes","no")
```

Edit: Just to make sure that the priciple is understood: you can check if ANY formula returns a number and then return a Yes or No.

```
=if(isnumber( AnyFormula ),"yes","no")
```

Comment: If that resolved your issue, please mark the answer as described in the [tour]. If it didn't, please leave a comment, so I can follow up.

Comment: Hello I tried that and it returned a Yes when the product name existed. Is there a way to first match to the product name (sheet3 B column), and then return Yes if the value in Column H is not Null, and No if its Null?

Comment: added a more generic formula to the answer

Comment: So I tried wrapping: =IF(ISNUMBER(INDEX('Sheet'!$I:$I, MATCH(Products!A3,'Sheet'!$A:$A,0)), "Yes", "No")  and got a "contains too many arguments" error

Comment: You are missing the closing bracket for the ISNUMBER(), which needs to be after the Index(Match()), so =IF(ISNUMBER(INDEX('Sheet'!$I:$I, MATCH(Products!A3,'Sheet'!$A:$A,0))), "Yes", "No")